# Problems sending array of favorites to a view in PHP via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, local-storage

I would like to know the best way to send this array of favorites to php, Im trying to use ajax, but I keep getting a 403 forbidden error. The path is correct, I must be doing something wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function(){
    var favorite = localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' );
    if (favorite  !== null){
        favorite = JSON.parse(favorite) || [];
    }
    $('.favorites' ).each(function() {
        var petid = $(this).attr('data-petid');
        if(favorite.indexOf(petid) !== -1){
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../assets/img/heart-red.svg)');
            $(this).css('background-color', '#fefefe');
        }
    });
     // This function changes the color of the heart on the landing page and stores the values into local storage
    $(".favorites").click(function() {

       var favorite = localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' );
       var petid = $(this).attr('data-petid');
       var index;

       favorite = JSON.parse(favorite) || [];

       if ((index = favorite.indexOf(petid)) === -1) {
          favorite.push(petid);
          $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../assets/img/heart-red.svg)');
          $(this).css('background-color', '#fefefe');
       }else {
          $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../assets/img/heart-full.svg)');
          $(this).css('background-color', '#25aae3');
          favorite.splice(index, 1);
       }
       localStorage.setItem('favorite', JSON.stringify(favorite) );
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/petlist/fuel/app/views/site/favorites.php',
          data: favorite,
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }

      });
    });

 });
```

Comment: Ajax is a perfectly acceptable solution for this. A simple $.post() will do what you want.

Comment: I was wondering if I'm calling this ajax call incorrectly, can somebody let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ajax calls in Fuel, use a controller that extends Controller_Rest

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request should look like this.

```
$.post('/petlist/fuel/app/views/site/favorites.php', { "favorite" : favorite }, function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Then in PHP, you can access the data via

```
print_r($_POST['favorite']);
```

Comment: I tried that, but I keep getting the 403 forbidden error. I'll keep trying thanks for the help.

Comment: That's just another way of writing the same thing he already has.

Comment: Correct. That being said, I'm pretty sure data : favorite is slightly different than data : { "favorite" : favorite }